# What happens when in struts configuration "xyz.do" is in forward path?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

This is a sample code from config file.

```
<action path="/admin/reloadLogging" 
           type="com.sap.isa.core.logging.ReloadLoggingAction">
     <forward name="success" path="/b2b/init.do"/>
</action>
```

I did not find any specific configuration for `/b2b/init.do`.

So my question is, where the request will be forwarded??

There is no JSP for it. Will it go again to the Action class?

Comment: It will be forwarded to /b2b/init.do, run through whatever Action is associated with that, then follow the relevant forward path from the Struts entry for it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :)That's what exactly the point is , There is no configuration of Action for "/b2b/init.do"

Comment: Then it will try to follow through and error, or there's a configuration for `init.do` in a separate WAR under the `b2b` context root.

Answer (score 0):

This request will be forwarded to the action class/servlet that handles the "b2b/init.do" request.

For example if you forwarded to the same url "reloadLogging" then you will find yourself in an infinite loop and get a "`StackOverflow`" error.

```
<action path="/admin/reloadLogging" 
           type="com.sap.isa.core.logging.ReloadLoggingAction">
     <forward name="success" path="/admin/reloadLogging.do"/>
</action>
```